# What does "Schi-Scha-Schubidupp" mean?

Tags: meaning, slang

The song "Wer hat Angst vor Dracula?" contains the text:

> Bei Nacht, bei Nacht, bei Nacht, bei Nacht, 
>   im schi-scha-schubidupp Mondenschein.

Is *Schi-Scha-Schubidupp* here a transmogrified adjective, or just nonsense-words inserted for aesthetic reasons?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

These are nonsense words like

> du-bi-du

or

> schalalalala

So there is no real meaning or translation for this.

There was a time in German music when using nonsense words like these quite regularly.
For example [this song](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDb05IUESGw) by a German cabaret artist.

Comment: Da da da. Ich lieb dich nicht, du liebst mich nicht. Aha.

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hSwJ2rjUSdc (for people who think @splattne is just expressing a lack of amorous feelings for Keyboardsurfer)

Comment: @balpha there is a song called "Da da da"?!?

Comment: @splattne And it’s a quite famous one ;)

Answer (score 3):

"Schubidupp" is somewhere inbetween [scat singing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scat_singing) and onomatopoeia. A precursor to beatboxing if you will :D

"Schi-Scha-Schubidupp" is a relatively common stylistic device. A rather popular example would be ["Schni-Schna-Schnappi"](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8FjywBCv_8E). You take the first syllable and prepend it twice, substituting the vocal with an "i" and "a" respectively.

> Der Text [...] verwendet die Stilfigur des „mehrere-Anläufe-mit-falschen-Vokalen“ („Schni-schna-schnappi“ wie in „Bi-Ba-Butzemann“)
>   - [Wikipedia](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schnappi#Stil_und_Inhalt_des_Songs)

Comment: Onomatopoeia for what?

Comment: @Tim N: For rhythm instruments. "Schu" could be a clap, snare or washboard, while "bidup" is a bass. If you add a quarter rest before the three syllables and loop it, you get a relatively decent swing rhythm.

Comment: Somehow I associate "Schubidu" with 1950s German Rock-and-Roll (Peter Kraus and such), though I couldn't find a reference to prove it.

Comment: While I associate it with Scooby-doo.

Comment: Der Schubidu: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XDb05IUESGw

Comment: @starblue It's common in a lot of early rock & roll in English as well, although of course it's spelled *shooby doo* instead.